# Input price formatting javascript , where wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Before you says its duplicate, I am not asking how to actually format the price. But asking where I am doing it wrong or what else I should do to implement it the way I want.

I did the price formatting ( actually by copying the code from somewhere )
http://jsfiddle.net/qwY24/

like for **price 1**

but now I want to format the price in the input field itself  (**price 2**), it work fine till 6 digit but then after that it get messed up. It got two problem

1. Format messed up **after 6 digit**
2. when press back key(delete number) the price doesn't **reformat after 6 digit only**

Code

```
$(".price1").on("keyup",function(){
   var price = $(this).val();
   $(".formatted1").text(price.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
});

$(".price2").on("keyup",function(){
   var price = $(this).val();
   price = price.replace(",","");
   $(".price2").val(price.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
   $(".formatted2").text(price.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
});
```

> ```
> <label>Price 1</label>
> <input type="text" class="price1" /><br />
> <label><b>Price 1 Formatted:</b></label>
> <span class="formatted1"></span><br /><br /><br />
>
> <label>Price 2</label>
> <input type="text" class="price2" /><br />
> <label><b>Price 2 Formatted</b></label>
> <span class="formatted2" ></span><br /><br /><br />
> ```

Comment: `\d\d\d` can be replaced by `\d{3}`. And try to use `*` `+` `?`. They compare 0 or more, 1 or more and 0 or 1.

Comment: @allendar thanks for that, But i don't yet really understand regex yet. I should spend sometime learning that  *that code was copied from somewhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`price.replace(",","")` replaces only the *first* instance of comma, not all of them. Replace it with

```
price = price.replace(/,/g,"");
```

(Also, the `.toString()` part in the next line is unnecessary because the variable is already a string.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwY24/3/

Comment: Thank you very much ... not a question but why haven't they made js replace as php str_replace :S ...easy to get confuse for newbies :(

Comment: @cjmling you may use the string input along with a global flag (g) as the third argument to make it behave like str_replace, bt it is considered as non-standard.

Comment: Good question, I certainly think `replace()` with a string should default to replace all.